# Battery percentage not accurate at all

Tags: battery

I've recently installed elementary OS Juno on a laptop and it seems like the way it discharges (according to Elementary) is extremely inaccurate. I'll charge the laptop, unplug it, it'll go alright for a bit, then suddenly drop from something like 30-40% to 5% and try to shut down, however the battery is not empty.

I'll keep it running and it'll stay on 1% for hours, until it then finally fully shuts down due to lack of power, and it won't turn on unless I charge it.

It keeps doing it and I was wondering if there's a way to fix this. It seems like it's a calibration issue or something. I've check the bios and the battery health is still good.

Comment: Welcome to eOS SE. Your Participation is much appreciated. This looks like some kind of bug. Check out a relevant issue [here](https://github.com/elementary/wingpanel-indicator-power/issues/93). If that's not your issue, I suggest you create one.

Comment: What laptop and battery do you have? Did you try calibrating the battery (just charging it until it says "full charge" then discharging it completely and charge it again to full) ? If you have `tlp` installed you can check the battery capacity with `sudo tlp-stat`.

Comment: Please let us know the updated situation.